# Would this be considered good OpSec?

Tags: opsec

```
Buy any altcoin on an exchange on the clearnet (on PC1 running OSX)
and have it converted to XMR wallet 1 (on PC2 running Tails)
Then send those coins from wallet 1 to another XMR wallet, wallet 2.
Finally wallet 2 to the marketplace where I wish to buy stuff
```

Of course I'd be waiting a couple days between each step. Would it be smart to at least do the last step on a crowded public wifi? I do not have any VPN whatsoever.

Just a couple days ago I thought I'd "just" setup a remote node on a PC which is on the clearnet and then somehow connect to it from a public wifi. All this just because my current USB-drive (8GB/ PC2) wouldn't have enough storage for the Monero blockchain. But as some people suggested that operating a remote node on a clearnet (PC1), of which I'd be the only user isn't safe; and also because I don't know much about Terminal/command line/SSH and would only be able to stick to internet guides I thought the following method should also do the job.

Would it be sufficient if I acquired myself a let's say 64GB USB-drive running Tails and have the blockchain downloaded on it? I would be following this guide step by step: https://medium.com/@Electricsheep56/sheeps-noob-guide-to-monero-gui-in-tails-3-2-d75c4e829c17

That guide recommends to download the blockchain onto an external drive, which confuses me. I do currently have an external HDD, which I have for normal/non-"anonymous" use. Could I instead of buying a 64GB USB-drive just have the blockchain downloaded on that and run Tails? Would that leave any trails or anything that could lead back to my activities on the HDD?

Would this be considered good OpSec?

Thanks!

Small question on the side: https://garlicgambit.wordpress.com/2017/04/16/monero-gui-on-tails-3/ This guide shows one how to create a bootable Tails with Monero preinstalled on it. I'm not really sure what that would be useful for if you can just download it directly from getmonero.org and use it instantly. Is it for that cold storage thing? Is "cold storage" needed if I just want to convert regular money into altcoins and spend it in a timespan of a month?

Answer (score 2):

It's fine for the HDD to have the blockchain installed on it as long as it has no ties to your wallet, Keep the wallet keys on the persistent storage.

Comment: Could you point me to a source confirming that please? Is it recommended to store it on a seperate partition on the HDD?

Comment: @skski11 The monero blockchain is nothing unique, this is stored on thousands of computers around the world and would identify you as monero user nothing more. However your wallet keys tie you to your actions this is why these should be protected.